# How to override com_users view

Tags: joomla-3.x, template-override

I would like to make a change to the username reminder page.  I had assumed that this would simply be a case of creating an template override thus:

/templates/mytemplate/html/com_users/remind/default.php

Alas, nothing happens.  Joomla! completely ignores my override.  Any ideas?  Are template overrides not valid for com_users?

It's driving me insane - almost to the point where I have considered buggering about with the core just to make it work.

Comment: I have used template overrides for com_users before.  What template are you using?  Try adding your override to protostar and see if it works there.

Comment: Hi, my template is an (only very slightly) hacked about version of protostar.  After a very frustrating day in which I achieve precisely nothing, I decided to install the Alpha for Joomla 4 (to see what exciting goodies are in store for us).  I tried this out there and, hey presto, it worked!  So now I think probably it's either an issue with 3.9.1 or my install is mangled. Will try out some variants of different installs, and templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I am officially an idiot.  My issue was that I have multiple templates for different parts of the site.  The component/user/view has no specific template assigned and is therefore using the default for the site.  Hence the changes I have been making all day to my template will have absolutely no impact on the screen!  Thank you for humouring an old fool.  I will get my coat!

Comment: Asking an honest question here should never lead to shame.  Simple / face-palm problems happen to everyone.  For this reason, posting your question articulately, and posting an answer that clarifies the issue just may help others.  Please remember to accept your answer when the system allows it.